# Unable to bind the selectedIndex of a DropDownList to the selectedIndex member of a Bindable class

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding

I am unable to bind the selectedIndex public property of a spark DropDownList to it's original source in the view's presentation model.

For the purposes of replicating this issue with as few lines as possible I have two views, and one presentation model. The code follows.

*Main.mxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               minWidth="955" 
               minHeight="600" 
               xmlns:views="com.blah.views.*">

    <views:DropDownListView/>

</s:Application>
```

*DropDownListView.mxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="300">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import com.blah.presentationmodels.DropDownListPresentationModel;

            [Bindable]
            private var pm:DropDownListPresentationModel = new DropDownListPresentationModel();
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:DropDownList id="myDropDownList" 
                    dataProvider="{pm.list}" 
                    selectedIndex="{pm.selectedIndex}" 
                    valueCommit="{pm.selectionChanged()}"/>

</s:Group>
```

*DropDownListPresentationModel.as*

```
package com.blah.presentationmodels
{
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

    [Bindable]
    public class DropDownListPresentationModel
    {
        public var selectedIndex:int = -1;
        public var list:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

        public function DropDownListPresentationModel()
        {
            list.addItem("Load of Bread");
            list.addItem("Stick of Butter");
            list.addItem("Carton of Milk");
        }

        public function selectionChanged():void
        {
            var newSelectedIndex:int = selectedIndex; // always -1
        }
    }
}
```

Debugging the application I find that selectedIndex in the presentation model always remains at the default value assigned regardless of which item I selected from the DropDownList. For the sample code above this is -1.

How can I bind the selectedIndex in the presentation model such that it is updated appropriately when the selected item DropDownList changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Debugging the application I find that selectedIndex in the
>   presentation model always remains at the default value assigned
>   regardless of which item I selected from the DropDownList. For the
>   sample code above this is -1.

That is correct based on the code you have provided.  You have bound the pm.selectedIndex to myDropDownList.selectedIndex.  So, whenever pm.selectedIndex changes, the value of myDropDownList.selectedIndex changes.

What you have not done is bound myDropDownList.selectedIndex to pm.selectedIndex.  So any changes to myDropDownList.selectedIndex will have absolutely no affect on pm.selectedIndex.  The easiest way to make this "Binding" work both ways is to use the shorthand MXML syntax:

```
<s:DropDownList id="myDropDownList" 
                selectedIndex="@{pm.selectedIndex}" />
```

[More information on that in the docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7cc0.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf64c3d-7ff4), which also include the "pre-Flex 4" alternative which is to use the binding tag:

```
<mx:Binding source="myDropDownList.selectedIndex" destination="pm.selectedIndex"/>
```